# Strings not displaying correctly in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I have a problem with my gridview where I'm appending to the end of a string each time through my for each loop, I try to remove the appending before it goes through the loop again (as seen in the below code) but it doesn't appear to be working:

```
Private Sub LoadData()

    conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    ds = New DataSet("Accounts")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [branch], [no] , [surname], [name], [type], [sub], [totalAmount], loc, locstatus, HoldCalc, odTimes " & _
                            "FROM [DmdOD]", conn)

    conn.Open()

    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Accounts")
    da.Fill(ds, "Accounts")

    conn.Close()

    Dim loc As String
    Dim hold As String
    Dim holdString As String
    Dim odString As String

    Dim tblAccounts As DataTable
    tblAccounts = ds.Tables("Accounts")

    'Clone table in order to manipulate data
    Dim dtClone As DataTable = tblAccounts.Clone()
    dtClone.Columns("loc").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
    dtClone.Columns("odtimes").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
    dtClone.Columns("HoldCalc").DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

    'Perform logic on fields before binding to gridview

    tblAccounts = DeleteDuplicateFromDataTable(tblAccounts, "no")

    For Each dr As DataRow In tblAccounts.Rows
        dtClone.ImportRow(dr)
        For Each drClone As DataRow In dtClone.Rows
            loc = drClone.Item("loc")
            odString = drClone.Item("odtimes")
            hold = drClone.Item("HoldCalc")
            If loc = "0.0000" Then
                loc = " "
                drClone.Item("loc") = loc
            End If

            'hold = CType(drClone.Item("HoldCalc"), Decimal)
            holdString = hold

            If loc <> "0.0000" AndAlso holdString < "0.0000" Then
                holdString &= " EX"
                drClone.Item("HoldCalc") = holdString
            ElseIf loc = "0.000" AndAlso hold < 0 Then
                holdString &= " OD"
                drClone.Item("HoldCalc") = holdString
            Else
                holdString = ""
                drClone.Item("HoldCalc") = holdString
            End If

            If odString = "0" Then
                odString = ""
                drClone.Item("odtimes") = odString
            End If

            If holdString.Length > 2 AndAlso (holdString.Contains(" EX EX") OrElse holdString.Contains(" OD OD")) Then
                drClone.Item("HoldCalc") = holdString.Substring(0, holdString.Length - 2)
            End If
        Next
    Next



    dtClone.AcceptChanges()


    GVAccounts.DataSource = dtClone
    GVAccounts.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Each time through the loop it just appends to the end of the string and although it steps into my If statement if the conditions are met, I still end up with the incorrect output. The output I want should only have EX or OD after the price but instead it outputs EX at the end many times and I don't want this....I hope that makes sense.

In any case I'm stumped as to how to fix this and Google has been no help with this, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a lot of sense that it would append many times, since you are looping through the rows in clone many times.

After you add the row from `tblAccounts` to `dtClone` you loop through all the rows in `dtClone` and perform your operations on the new row and all the ones before it, so it is normal that you are ending with the string being appended many times.

Why don't you just clone the row from `tblAccounts`, process it and then add it to `dtClone`?

Comment: I need to change the datatype of the row in order to process it, which is what I'm doing there. Since the row is already established in tblAccounts I have to clone it in order to change the values.

Comment: Or from my understanding anyways.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but you are looping through all the rows in 'dtClone' many times, which is not necessary. And each time you are adding "EX"s, which is why you end up with the wrong format.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to go about doing what you suggest, do you think you could provide a code example if you're able?

Comment: Just take out the first loop and do something like `dtClone = tblAccounts.Clone` and then loop through the rows of `dtClone` and process. It should be a lot faster as well.
Alternatively, do not loop through `dtClone`, but do `clonedRow = dr.Clone()`, process and then add to `dtClone`.

Comment: No worries! But don't forget that you can just use the `.Clone()` method on the datatable to clone the whole thing in one go. Saves a few lines of code and is probably a bit faster :)